# Triggering StepFunction with EventBridge with Serverless

Tags: serverless, aws-step-functions

I've set an event inside a Step Function as following:

```
      events:
        - S3EventBridge:
            Type: EventBridgeRule
            Properties:
              EventBusName: default
              pattern:
                source:
                  - aws.s3
                detail-type:
                  - Object Created
                detail:
                  bucket:
                    name:
                      - "${self:custom.xxxx.${self:provider.stage}}-${self:provider.stage}"
                  object:
                    key:
                      - prefix: 'payloads/to_process'
```

Stack is deployed successfully, but when I put a new object in the bucket, at the specified path nothing happens.

I enabled the EventBridge in the S3 resource:

```
    Data:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: "${self:custom.xxxx.${self:provider.stage}}-${self:provider.stage}"
        NotificationConfiguration:
          EventBridgeConfiguration:
            EventBridgeEnabled: True
```

If I attach the identical EventBridge event to a Lambda it works, correctly triggering it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I ran into a similar issue and thought it's worth updating.

Did you check that the eventBridge rule itself got created? For me that wasn't the case when I used to specify the event like you did above.

If you create it like below it should do what you want:

```
      events:
        - eventBridge:
            name: MyEventBridgeRule
            properties:
              EventBusName: default
            event:
              source:
                - aws.s3
              detail-type:
                - Object Created
              detail:
                bucket:
                  name:
                    - !Sub "${self:custom.xxxx.${self:provider.stage}}-${self:provider.stage}"
                object:
                  key:
                    - prefix: 'payloads/to_process'
```